Connect react native expo app to backend open server panel
I have a react native expo app. This application worked successfully with xampp in the past. When I sent requests, the link was http://{127.0.0.0}/stars/stars.php.
On the open server panel the same file is in the folder stars.local, path=https://stars.local/stars.php, and this requests not work, i get network error․
This link opens fine in the browser․
I understand that {127.0.0.0} is the localhost, but I don’t understand why the request isn’t going through. I didn't find anything like this in the search․
What needs to be changed in the open server panel to make it work?
I tried to change stars.local part to server ip address, but it doesn't work again.
